# Converting Request scoped bean to JSON string

Tags: spring, spring-boot, objectmapper, requestscope

I was facing an issue while converting a bean with request scope to JSON using object mapper. It thows an exception like below. Not sure what am missing. I couldn't find any  relatable resource on the web. Can someone explain what should be the way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Line of code :

planInfo -> Bean with request scope

`String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(planInfo);`

Exception :

`"timestampSeconds":1630567890,"timestampNanos":683000000,"severity":"ERROR","thread":"qtp133294616-216","logger":"com.signup.api.service.SignupService","message":"exception \ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader[\"unnamedModule\"]-\u003ejava.lang.Module[\"classLoader\"]-....`

PlanInfo

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.RequestScope;

@Data
@Component
@RequestScope
public class PlanInfo {
  String additionalPlanDetails;
  String additionalServiceCost;
  String listOfAdditionalServiceIds;

  String planMinutes;
  String planPrice;
  String totalamt;

  String setUpFee;
  String selectedPlanId;
  String canadaProvince;

  String vatAmount;
  String vatPercentage;
  String netTotalAmt;

  String selectedIvrPlanId;
  String selectedIvrPlanMinutes;
  String selectedIvrPlanPrice;

  String totalPlanPrice;
  String totalAmtAfterDiscount;
  boolean waiveSetupFee;
  String planCategory;
}
```

Comment: Don't try to send a request scoped bean, as you will actually be sending the proxy not the underlying object. As this proxy contains references to context etc. you will get into this issue (assuming `@RequestScope` here). Also if your bean references bean a, which references bean b, which references bean a, you get a recursive error.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace (which should be visible in the logging, you only included the error message you get in your webbrowser/client.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes, it seems bit hard to do things with proxied bean. Also we don't have any other bean referece in this bean(with request scope) so there is no way for recusive DI here. So, we decided to remove the request scope from this bean and added a new helper bean with request scope. so our helper bean is not coupled with  the response.